# F# Shortening pattern matching on a tree

Tags: f#

Not sure if this is the right place for this question, but I have a function, which I'm pretty sure can be simplified, but I'm not sure how.

```
let rec probOK = function
| Branch(ds, p, Leaf l1, Leaf l2) when p <= 1.0 && p >= 0.0     ->  true
| Branch(ds, p, b1, b2)           when p <= 1.0 && p >= 0.0     ->  probOK b1 && probOK b2
| Branch(ds, p , b1, Leaf l1)     when p <= 1.0 && p >= 0.0     ->  probOK b1
| Branch(ds, p , Leaf l2, b2)     when p <= 1.0 && p >= 0.0     ->  probOK b2
| _                                                             ->  false
```

The task is to define a function that takes a `probability tree` (see below) and check whether it satisfies that every probability `p` is `0 <= p <= 1`. A `probability tree` has the type

```
type ProbTree = | Branch of string * float * ProbTree * ProbTree
                | Leaf of string
```

What is meant by `probability tree` is a tree to represent sample spaces of sequential processes, where the outcomes at each stage in the process is either a success or failure.

An example of a `probability tree`, where a six-sided die is thrown and the probability that it's `>2` is `2/3`, the probability it's `<= 2` is `1/3` and so on:

[image: Probability tree]

In my example, the probability tree I'm working on is:

```
let test = Branch(">2",0.67, Branch(">3",0.5, Leaf "A", Leaf "B")
                           , Branch(">3",0.5, Leaf "C", Leaf "D"))
```

which would return true, as all the probabilities `p` are within 0 and 1.

Now, the function I've defined works, but I feel like the pattern matching could be simplified, perhaps by doing something akin to `([],Leaf _ )-> true`, but I can't quite figure it out.

Any hints?

EDIT1: A shortened suggestion (now with less whitespace):

```
let rec probOK = function
| Branch(ds, p, b1, b2) when p <= 1.0 && p >= 0.0 ->  probOK b1 && probOK b2
| Leaf _                                          ->  true
| _                                               ->  false
```

Comment: That function doesn't seem to work with your example because because you're missing the case where a branch contains 2 branches.

Comment: True. I posted the wrong version of the function, but I've updated the post now.

Comment: FYI I've edited my answer below to something completely different.

Comment: EDIT1 looks good, aside from the whitespace :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simplify the code by separating out the traversing of tree nodes from acting on them. Here's a function that checks if a node is valid:

```
let nodeProbOk = function
| Branch(_, p, _, _)-> p <= 1.0 && p >= 0.0
| Leaf _ -> true
```

Here's a function that tests that all nodes satisfy a predicate:

```
let rec forAllNodes pred = function
| Branch(_, _, a, b) as branch -> pred branch && forAllNodes pred a && forAllNodes pred b
| Leaf _ as leaf               -> pred leaf
```

And this is how you would use them together:

```
test |> forAllNodes nodeProbOk
```

The advantage of this approach is that you have two relatively simple functions and you can reuse `forAllNodes` for purposes other than validation. This limits the number of places that you need to use recursion in your code and should make things easier to reason about.

Comment: That's a good suggestion. What do you think of the suggestion in EDIT1?